# Changing sql adapter in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4, sqlite

I have been using sqlite for my project, 
made alot of changes in migration files, I want to upload to heroku, but it does not support sqlite, so I decided to change it to pg.

I changed the database.yml file to the right values, I try to migrate the database, but I get tons of errors of migration, where I decided backthen to remove a column, but it doesn't exist anymore.

Is there anyhow to create a migration file out of the current fine working database in sqlite, that will be put in one migration file to be migrated in pg version ?

Comment: can you add migration error, normally a migration run normally on all DB

Answer (score 0):

This is an example of the configuration of a test database, actually it can be production or development if you want:

```
test:
  adapter: mysql2
  database: redmine_test
  host: localhost
  username: 'user'
  password: 'password'
  port: 3306
  reconnect: true
  encoding: utf8

test_sqlite3:
  adapter: sqlite3
  database: db/test.db

test_pgsql:
  adapter: postgresql
  database: redmine_development
  host: localhost
  username: user
  password: 'password'
```

When you use `rake db:migrate` it will try to execute the migrations for all of your environments, this is Production/Development/Test.
If you want to specify the environment use this command instead:

`rake db:migrate RAILS_ENV=NameOfTheEnviroment`